# SlickGrid CSS styles wrong on filtered view

Tags: slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid with dataview working pretty good, grid and dataview are synced up for modify and delete selections using syncGridSelection, however an interesting problem occurs on the changed CSS styles.  The changed rows CSS stlye are being applied to the same "visible" row number in the grid when I choose a filter set that does not include the actual changed rows.  The sort works fine, but I noticed that the filter is not working.  Does anyone have a fix for this?  Can you paste as much info and code for me as possible because I'm new to SlickGrid.  I pasted code that loads up the grid.

```
function LoadGridData() {
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetConfigurations")', function (rows) {
                if (rows.length > 0) {
                    if (rows[0].id = 'undefined') {
                        $(rows).each(function (index) {
                            rows[index].newAttribute = "id"
                            rows[index]["id"] = index;
                        });
                    }
                };
                data = rows;
                dataView.beginUpdate();
                dataView.setItems(data);
                dataView.setFilter(filter);
                dataView.endUpdate();

                // Refresh the data render
                grid.invalidate();
                grid.render();
                grid.setSelectedRows([]);

                dataView.syncGridSelection(grid, true);

            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

After debugging I found that I had used an older example of marking css changed in function getItemMetadata.  The correct code is below.  Previously I was referencing data[row].  When Syncing DataView to Grid, the getItem() method returns the correct row. In this case my DataState is my own changed indicator on the view model.

```
  dataView.getItemMetadata = function (row) {
            var item = this.getItem(row);
            if (item && item.DataState == 2) {
                return {
                    "cssClasses":
                        "changed"

                };
            }
```